# Sending a message from a frame to the Main Form

Tags: delphi, message

I have a VCL Form Application consisting of three units.  Unit 1 defines the form and includes many instances of a frame with multiple Tlabel components which is defined in Unit 2.  Unit 3 declares various shared constants and variables which may be used throughout the program.

When the user clicks on one of the frames it sets certain values for variables in Unit 2 and must notify the Form to take actions affecting other cells and components on the form.  Since including Unit 1 in the uses clause of Unit 3 would create a circular reference, I thought sending a message to the Form would be the best option for executing the required actions.

In my first attempt I set things up as follows:

```
Unit 1
Interface
Uses ..., Winapi.Messages, Unit2, Unit3;
Type
Form1 = Class(TForm);
//List of frames and components
...
private
...
    { Private declarations }
procedure OnDisplayMessage(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_MY_MESSAGE;
...
End;

Implementation
...    
procedure TForm1.OnDisplayMessage(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  TakeAction (inputlist); 
end;


Unit 2  //Common program constants and variables
Interface

const
  WM_MY_MESSAGE = WM_USER + 100;
 ... 


Unit 3  //Frame component definition
interface
Uses ...Winapi.Messages, Unit2;

Types
  TCellFrame = class(TFrame)
    Item1: TLabel;
    Item2: TLabel;
    Item3: TLabel;
    Item4: TLabel;
    Item5: TLabel;
    Item6: TLabel;
    Item7: TLabel;
    Item8: TLabel;
    Item9: TLabel;
    procedure FrameClick(Sender: TObject);

Implementation    
  procedure TCellFrame.FrameClick(Sender: TObject);
  begin
     ...
     SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST,WM_MY_MESSAGE,0,0);
     ...
  end;
```

Although the code compiled, The required actions were not executed. I assumed that the message was not being passed to the form so I then tried a substituting the Windows method `AppHookFunction ()` for `OnDisplayMessage ()` as follows:
Unit 1

```
Interface
Uses ..., Winapi.Messages, Unit2, Unit3;
Type
Form1 = Class(Tform;)
//List of frames and components
...
private
...
    { Private declarations }
    function AppHookFunc(var Message : TMessage) : Boolean;    
...
End;

Implementation
...    
function TForm1.AppHookFunc(var Message : TMessage) : Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  if Message.Msg = WM_MY_MESSAGE then begin
    TakeAction (inputlist);
    Result := True;
  end;
end;


Unit 2  //Common program constants and variables
Interface

const
  WM_MY_MESSAGE = WM_USER + 100;
 ... 


Unit 3  //Frame component definition
interface
Uses ...Winapi.Messages, Unit2;

Types
  TCellFrame = class(TFrame)
    Item1: TLabel;
    Item2: TLabel;
    Item3: TLabel;
    Item4: TLabel;
    Item5: TLabel;
    Item6: TLabel;
    Item7: TLabel;
    Item8: TLabel;
    Item9: TLabel;
    procedure FrameClick(Sender: TObject);

Implementation    
  procedure TCellFrame.FrameClick(Sender: TObject);
  begin
     ...
     SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST,WM_MY_MESSAGE,0,0);
     ...
  end;
```

This options also appears to fail to send the message.  The basic actions work fine when tested so I am fairly certain the failure is in passing the message.  Do I have a misunderstanding in the way messages should pass from frame to Form or is there another approach to implement an action in the form generated by the frame onclick event?

Comment: Yeah, some misunderstanding, some confusion, probably some copy paste error...  In first snippet you're listening for WM_DISPLAY_CLEARLIST, but sending WM_MY_MESSAGE. In second snippet it is unclear why AppHookFunc would process any message at all.

Comment: First, you don't need to broadcast, there's a parenting relation between the form and frames. You can get to the form from the frames by GetParentForm.

Comment: Second, I don't think messaging is required for this but you can get around circular referencing by referencing the other way around from the implementation section. I think you'd better use some sort of callback. The form can set a method address to a frame property for the frames to callback when they want.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Re: WM_DISPLAY_CLEARLIST.  I changed the Message to WM_MY_MESSAGE when I extracted code for this question but missed it in one location.  The question has been corrected.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz re: Second...  Could you expand upon how working the other way around would be executed in an answer?

Comment: You seem to have missed @Sertac's first comment. You don't need a message at all here to reach the parent form. You can do it diectly by using `GetParentForm` from the frame.

Comment: You'd like to correct the units too. In the first paragraph you say unit2 is frames and labels, unit3 is constants etc.. In the snippet unit2 is constants, unit3 is frames, labels. In fact in general don't extract code for questions. Prepare a [mcve] and you won't have these problems and we won't have these problems.

Comment: In unit2 (3?) in the implementation section use unit1. Then in any method you can access the parent form ( TForm1(GetParentForm(Self, True) ).

Comment: First of all, having a hard reference to unit1 is bad desing from my opinion. So apart from the circular reference problem, the message sollution isn’t a bad idea. But when sending a message you should use the forms handle to message to. And as Sertac said, you can get the parent form using GetParentForm: so you can do ‘SendMessage(GetParentForm(...).Handle,...)’.